# Find a reference to a table in DTS packages

Tags: sql-server, dts

I need to find a DTS package that contains a specific table name. There are 200+ DTS packages each with multiple objects in them.

My_Prod is the table name. Is there a T-SQL command to find all the DTS packages that reference this table name?

Comment: Do you really mean DTS and not SSIS? What version of SQL Server are you running?

Answer (score 2):

As Eric said, there isn't a SQL command that I am aware of.

You could take a look at [SSIS-DTS Package Search](http://gerasus.com/).  I've never used it but it looks like it may work for what you need.

Also, you could take a look at [this article](http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/larsen8).  I slightly modified the code from it to search all DTS packages on a server and change connection settings that were pointed towards a specific server.  It would be a little work but you might be able to get it to do what you want.

Hope this helps.

Comment: This article [http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/larsen8](http://www.dbazine.com/sql/sql-articles/larsen8)  has saved my day

Answer (score 1):

There's no SQL command, but the files are XML-based, so you can do a Windows search on the file contents to see if your table name pops up in any of them.

Comment: Did you search inside the file? I think it's a different search box on Windows search.